# Remove public address from my wallet

Tags: wallet, vanity-address

I have generated few fancy bitcoin addresses with vanitygen. I was looking on some webpage how-to-add the address into my bitcoin wallet. 
I accidentally entered the example private key instead of my generated one.
Now I have in my wallet someone else's address and plenty of transactions.

Is there a way how to remove that address from my wallet?
I did more actions since the last backup.

The only way I came to is to backup private keys from my wallet and add them to some empty wallet.

Comment: What wallet client are you using?

Comment: I have the original bitcoin client (bitcoind + bitcoin-qt)

Answer (score 0):

Jackjack's fork of pywallet will allow you to delete a private key, reportedly.

- http://pywallet.tk
- http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=294439.0